# User Cancelled Dialog (4201) error when logging in Facebook

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, ionic2, facebook-login

i'm trying to make facebook login in ionic 2 app.
i get this error when i'm trying to log in with chrome://inspect or in my smartphone

> Object {errorCode: "4201", errorMessage: "User cancelled dialog"}
>   [image]

that's my facebookLogin code

```
 loginWithFacebook(){
Facebook.login(['email']).then((response) => {
  alert('Logged in');
  alert(JSON.stringify(response.authResponse));
},(error)=>{
  alert(error);
})
```

}

in android emulator it works fine.

i checked in chrome://inspect and in ion-view app(of ionic 2) then i see this problem..
i see the login and then when i press facebook login it's open in different page the confirm and i can't press ok

in addition when i try some times i get this
[image]

[image]